# CUPS server not working properly from source

Tags: cups

I recently tried to install the latest version of CUPS to my raspberry pi, which, the only current way to do so is to compile it. After doing the usual procedure (./configure, make, sudo make install), everything installed, but localhost:631 is not available. When I started up my pi up recently, the boot sequence showed this:

```
Failed to start SYSV: Startup/shutdown script for CUPS.. see 'systemctl status cups.service' for details.
```

Is there an extra step to configure cups that hasn't been configured yet?

Answer (score -2):

I think this guide might help you 
http://www.howtogeek.com/169679/how-to-add-a-printer-to-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-computer/

Comment: In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.